# How to detect if an unstable feature is enabled?

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to detect if an unstable feature (e.g., [`let_chains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/let-chains.html)) is enabled in Rust 1.75. It seems like, `cfg!(feature = "let_chains")` should do it, but it doesn't. See this example:

```rust
#![feature(let_chains)]

fn main() {
    assert!(
        dbg!(cfg!(feature = "let_chains")) || dbg!(cfg!(let_chains)),
        "OK, then. How do you detect if an unstable feature is enabled?"
    );
}
```

The output is:

```plaintext
[src/main.rs:5] cfg!(feature = "let_chains") = false
[src/main.rs:5] cfg!(let_chains) = false
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:4:5:
OK, then. How do you detect if an unstable feature is enabled?
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b37f00d5cd3c1da65c7b5e498c47454e)

Is there a way to detect if an unustable feature has been enabled?

---

For a little more background, I'm doing this in a proc macro, so I'm trying to use `cfg!()` to generate the correct code based on whether certain unstable features are enabled. I could use the `#[cfg()]` attribute, if that somehow worked while the `cfg!` macro didn't. But I get [the same results with the `#[cfg()]` attribute](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf867f46790a0f390a5a63ccf062e7a6).

Comment: I believe usually crates just have a feature "backtrace" the user of the crate enables to specify they want backtrace support, instead of the library automatically detecting of the user has the backtrace feature. This also lets users selectively choose where they want a backtrace to exist, instead of it being a global option.

Comment: It's just an example. I'm trying to find out how to detect if an unstable feature is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to detect whether a certain unstable feature was enabled. All you can do is detect whether the user is running a nightly.

Usually, the way to go is to have a Cargo feature in your macro that will change how it expands the code.

Alternatively, if you can place the code that requires the feature in your own crate (a helper crate for the proc-macro, as commonly done), you can use a build script of this crate to detect whether the user is running nightly, and if yes, enable that feature (for your own crate).

Comment: The build script to detect nightly end enable the feature for my crate seems like the most promising approach. Thanks. This looks to be a way to detect nightly: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/add-unstable-feature-only-if-compiled-on-nightly/27886/2